# Why do I get unexpected token?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

I am trying to search for `.c`, `.cpp` or `.h` files in a text file contains list of files.  However, when I have problems when I ran:

```
$ grep -sr ^.*\.(c|cpp|h)$ .
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: Because `(` has a special meaning in bash. You need to escape it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - Not to escape, that would be `\(`, but put the regex pattern to quotes...

Comment: Escaping would work as well, however.

Comment: `$ grep -sr "^.*\.(c|cpp|h)$" .` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Unix box to test but:

```
grep -sr '^.*\.(c|cpp|h)$' .
```

... should at least not trigger a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You should be good with

```
grep -sr '\.(c|cpp|h)$' .
```

1. Regex pattern should be in quotes
2. There is no need to include `^.*` part in the pattern